# need help with 2 sentences. can't understand them

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Before acting on such insights it is advisable to confirm them with additional descriptive research or to use causal designs. For example, a customer review
>   might suggest new creative for an email ad. The new ad, however, should be tested against a control.

I cannot understand the last 2 sentences. Particularly "new creative for an email ad" and "tested against a control"

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include quotes from dictionaries outlining what you suspect are the most relevant definitions for each of the words which has confused you.

Comment: "suggest new creative for an email ad" doesn't make sense.  I wouldn't like to guess at what it's supposed to be.

Comment: @MaxWilliams It does; its marketerese: *creative* is a noun.

Comment: for "creative" I haven't suspected any of the definitions given in the dictionaries I used. as for "control", I haven't suspected any.

Comment: As @MaxWilliams says 'creative' in this context is jargon peculiar to the marketing industry. 'Testing against a control' should be easily found online; the first hit I got in a search was about email advertising campaigns.

Comment: Well, what do you think the sentences mean? Also, why do you think what you think is wrong? And if you think what you think is wrong, why do you still think it?

Comment: @DanBron - a "creative" in that sense is like a "copy writer".  So if the sentence was "For example, a customer review might suggest new copy writer for an email ad." then it's still ungrammatical to say the least.  it's not obvious to me that that was what was intended.  Sure we can guess, but it's not a good idea, that's what I meant.

Comment: I can put more context if necessary?

Comment: @MaxWilliams No, not *creative*, the count noun, *creative*, the mass noun (what the count noun *creative* produces).

Comment: Please add a link to your source: http://blog.mikezhang.com/files/socialcrm.pdf

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*"New creative for an email ad"* is awkward. I would guess the author wanted to say *"new creative **ideas** for an email ad"*. The meaning is now clear hopefully.

*"Tested against a control"* means that it should be tested on a group of users first to validate its effectiveness. This is from the commonly used term [**control group**](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+control+group) in research.

Comment: MHmm that seem to make more sense now. thanks anyways. the second one is fully clear now though. thank you.